# Perl script run in some browsers but not others

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a perl script running on a webserver which appears to run fine from some browsers, but not in others. On machine A it runs in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari. On machine B it runs in Chrome but not in Firefox or Safari. Here is a screen shot of two browsers:
[image]

Any ideas as to why this might happen?

Comment: According to the error message, you don't have the JSON module installed.

Comment: How are you 'running' perl in your browsers? But the error message says you don't have `JSON` installed. Try installing that.

Comment: Thanks. It's a web host and so can't install JSON, but can I download it myself and 'use lib' or something similar from within my script?

Answer (score 1):

The error you showed is an inability to locate `JSON.pm` in response to doing `use JSON;` or `require JSON;`. Install the module using your system's package manager.

Comment: Thanks. But why would it run OK from one browser (outputting JSON correctly) and not in another?

Comment: Well, do you get the same `use JSON;` statement of the same script in all cases? If so, the search path can be influenced by environment variables. Add `BEGIN { print(STDERR "$_: $ENV{$_}\n") for sort grep /^PERL/, keys %ENV; }` before `use JSON;` and report what it ouputs.